# Como configurar usuario y contraseña en mariadb

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Instale mariadb mediante la linda de comandos.
Intento acceder como usuario root le doy enter pero me pide contraseña.
Ya intente modificar el archivo  muy.cnf agregándole esta linea

```
12 [client]
13 user=root
14 password=pass
```

le puse este comando para configurar

```
$ mysql_install_db
```

**
Pero me sale este error
mysql.user table already exists!
Run mysql_upgrade, not mysql_install_db
**
tambien le puse este. Comando

````
$ mysqld_safe -u root & ```
Pero igual me sale este error
**
[1] 2012
.../usr/etc $ 210204 08:47:15 mysqld_safe Logging to '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/var/lib/mysql/localhost.err'.
210204 08:47:15 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
**
Y tambien intente de esta manera

**
````

mysql_secure_installation

```
pero me sale esto:
**
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket mysqld.sock
**
es que hice la instalación de Phpmyadmin viaje composer, pero no se si me afectaría a mariadb.

Accedo a localhost:8080 y al querer ingresar usuario root sin contraseña y me marca este error
**
 El inicio de sesión sin contraseña está prohibido por la configuración (ver AllowNoPassword)
**
Tambienes le pongo usuario root y contraseña pasa pero me marca este error
**
El servidor MySQL no autorizó su acceso**
Y en el pie de pagina otro error
**
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
**
```

Comment: Me suena a permisos de usuario. Lo primero que hay que hacer después de instalar MariaDB/MySQL: `$ sudo mysql_secure_installation` y seteas el passw de root y otras cosas. Luego en PHPMyAdmin en el archivo config.inc.php: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';`

Comment: Y como si al introducir el códigos Enter current password for root (enter for none): me pide contra, como no me la se le doy entre pero me marca este error: current password for root (enter for none):
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket mysqld.sock' (2)